# Apache ant fail to run bash script

Tags: bash, ant

I have a simple test script called `alarm.sh`. It looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cust_func(){
    sleep 10
    echo "Sleep $1 times..."
}


for i in {1,2,3,4,5}
do
    cust_func $i &
done
echo "script end"
```

If I run the script with `./alarm.sh`, it will run as expected in a parallel way and generate result like:

```
Sleep 2 times...
Sleep 3 times...
Sleep 1 times...
Sleep 4 times...
Sleep 5 times...
script end
```

But I need to run the script by apache ant, it looks like the script has ran but part of the result is missing. 
The apache ant target:

```
<target name="TodAlarmsDryRun" depends="build">
        <exec executable="/bin/bash" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="${output.dir}/bin/alarm.sh" />
        </exec>
</target>
```

The result generated using apache ant:

```
script end
```

You can see all the sleep message are misssing.

I suspect the ant is not working with bash script properly. Especially the shell script has parallel work. Because if I remove the parallel keyword `&`, it can show the result. But it is not running in the parallel way. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

You are detaching the execution of cust_func from the current shell so it executes in a different shell, that's why the output is lost.
You can redirect output to a file a read it **after** the script has finished.

```
 cust_func $i >> cust_func.log &
```

Comment: Where do I detach it?  Could you point it out? It will be very helpful if you can do this. Also I open the "px" to check but I do not see the bash process running.

Comment: The & (ampersand) at the end of the command makes the call to run in background, that means in a sub-shell. You can list them with **ps -lf -C bash**

Comment: There is not bash script is running. So it means the command is not running.

Comment: try with sleep command **ps- lf -C sleep**. Also **ps -efH | grep -E 'bash|sleep'**. Increase the sleep time to get more chances to catch them.